# Upload files to AWS S3 using Spring Boot works fine without Proxy but fails with Proxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-s3, proxy

Uploading files to AWS S3 using spring boot works great when it executed without proxy and when I add proxy in the VM args it fails with following error,

```
Internal Server Error (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 500; Error Code: 500 Internal Server Error; Request ID: null; S3 Extended Request ID: null; Proxy: 192.168.1.171)
```

Below are the vm arguments that I have provided,

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.1.171 -Dhttp.proxyPort=9999 -Dhttps.proxyHost=192.168.1.171 -Dhttps.proxyPort=9999
```

When I started to execute the package the AWS SDK auto initialize the proxy as it finds in the args list
and it prints in the console

```
com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient - Configuring Proxy. Proxy Host: 192.168.1.171 Proxy Port: 9999
```

I can not remove the proxy because I am using Oauth2 authentication in spring security.
Is there any way that I can disable auto initializing the proxy in AWS SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue after contacting AWS, I had to configure the method “setNoneProxyHosts (String nonProxyHosts)” method in the ClientConfiguration class. This sets the optional hosts the client will access without going through the proxy.
The parameter – “nonProxyHosts” takes the hosts the client will access without going through the proxy. Please follow this link here for more information about the class and the method: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html#setNonProxyHosts-java.lang.String-

Based on the instructions provided by AWS Support I had amended the config and added following;

```html
public ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration() {
   final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
   clientConfiguration.setNonProxyHosts("*.s3.<ZONE>.amazonaws.com|*.s3-<ZONE>.amazonaws.com");
   return clientConfiguration;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In effect to communicate over a network "endpoints" are an address, but links require "connections" so it may be more of a connection/connected "host conflict" by configuration.
For example i could have both a webserver and a DB that takes requests via http direct but it depends if they are configured for each other and/or to be connected through an irq to network to anything else.

Comment: Is there any way that I can disable auto initializing the proxy in AWS SDK?

Comment: Read this, i see some of the problem is "what" requires to be configured to commit authentication" ! ...."This has led many developers and API providers to incorrectly conclude that OAuth is itself an authentication protocol and to mistakenly use it as such. Let's say that again, to be clear:

OAuth 2.0 is not an authentication protocol.".... https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/

Comment: My Oauth2 authentication works perfectly. but providing `-Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.1.171 -Dhttp.proxyPort=9999 -Dhttps.proxyHost=192.168.1.171 -Dhttps.proxyPort=9999` as the arguments when I run the application, AWS SDK is taking the arguments and auto assigning it to its proxy. Is there anyway that I can turn off the proxy for AWS and not use proxy for AWS S3. Because if I dont use proxy the AWS S3 works.

Comment: They do not appear to be the correct parameters anyhow.   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/http_proxy_config.html

Comment: If not, how do the client applications connect to authentication server which is running on behind the proxy?

Comment: "client applications" - be more specific... spring boot? or people typing amazon.com? If you mean Spring , then a proxy is a request response handler pass through transparently to handle your internet address much similar to a router and port forwarding, a router "seems alike" a server.

Comment: nb: ... and a proxy or a router to the outside is often referred to as a "gateway".

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-proxy.html   and   https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/getting-started-with-spring-boot-on-aws-part-1/   You should understand that if you are not "sending" to the address and port on your command-line , then your port should be bound to an IRQ. Also, in all this it makes reference to Corretto SDK and a CLI command-line service from Amazon.

Comment: One point, What ! is the proxy ? Another machine or extra software. However, noting the command line seems to be Java, look for a proxy in the SDK Java control panel in its /bin folder. In previous years when Java was installed the main user account menu had an entry for Java for various other startable features. It may be in those in the /bin folder (where Java executable is).

Comment: To cross reference the following their should be settings in your spring boot project XML configuration file.   https://java.com/en/download/help/proxy_setup.html

Comment: Thank you, and it seems like I need to research on the topic.